# "Calling a spade a spade": synonymous expressions?

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests, synonyms

I'm looking for expressions that are equivalent to

> "calling a spade a spade."

In some environments and verbal contexts, this phrase needs to be avoided -- please take my word for it.

Thank you.

#### UPDATE

---

I shouldn't have used the gerund in my question.  Where I need to use this sort of expression is in a discussion I'm losing patience with, and I want to say, effectively, let's not pussyfoot around with euphemisms. @Tushar Raj's *I'm going to tell it like it is*, and
@undergroundmonorail's *Let's not mince words here*, both work quite well.  Thank you all.

In response to @Pharap,

> Do you have evidence that someone has taken offence at this before or
> is this merely preemptive?

I want to avoid problems.  I live in a small town where everybody has their sensitivities.  I was once in a hiring committee where a person objected to someone calling one of the candidates a "dark horse."  I believe I read that some town in California decided not to use the term "manhole covers" any more because of the "man" syllable.

--

[image: screenshot]

Comment: For those who aren't aware, 'spade' is slang for African-American. It's not as bad sounding as others but is still pejorative.

Comment: Somehow I think calling a spade a synonymous expression misses the point.

Comment: @Mitch - "Most authorities" feel that the "spade" referred to is a digging implement, not an African-American.  However, the point is well taken that some may take offense at the phrase.

Comment: Wikipedia [backs up](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_a_spade_a_spade) what @HotLicks said: The phrase predates the use of the word "spade" as an ethnic slur against African Americans, which was not recorded until 1928; however, in contemporary U.S. society, the idiom is often avoided due to potential confusion with the slur or confusion with playing card references such as "black as the ace of spades".

Comment: @HotLicks Yes, the primary meaning of spade is as a small shovel, and it has quite a few other distinct meanings, but the pejorative one was relevant to the OP.

Comment: "If it walks like a duck, quacks like a duck, ... It is a duck"

Comment: We French say "call a cat a cat" but surely the racist variant is nice too…

Comment: I suppose "calling a spade a fucking shovel" won't do.  (It's a phrase that was a favorite of one former coworker of mine.)

Comment: @HotLicks I usually go with ‘calling a spade an excavator’ because I like to think big.

Comment: This does depend a lot on your audience. I doubt most younger people are even aware that spade can be used as a racial slur, and I'm fairly certain those that do wouldn't mistake 'call a spade a spade' to be offensive. As for the older population, I'm fairly certain most of them are aware of the expression and would not misinterpret it. Do you have evidence that someone has taken offence at this before or is this merely preemptive?

Comment: Why not call calling a spade a spade calling a spade a spade?

PS: Youngster here, had no idea 'spade' doubled as a slur.

Comment: While the "say/tell it like it is" answers are likely best, I rather like "call a shovel a shovel". It has the advantage of being delightfully ironic, because it describes the thing you are, by changing the phrase, precisely not doing! :D

Comment: Here in the UK 'spade' *used* to apply to anyone of non-white heritage, not just African/Caribbean people. And Tushar is entirely correct - tread carefully with this one ;-)

Comment: @HotLicks, I'm guessing your former coworker got it from the first joke here: http://www.8052.com/forum/read/121600

Comment: It has some racial connections you may want to stay away from...... People of color (Black) used to be called Spades in 1950s America - not a politically correct term today!

Comment: @DewiMorgan - Now there's a Comment that should be an Answer if I ever saw one!

Comment: @aparente001 I've added it in the answer below!

Comment: @G3V - Sorry, I was talking to Dewi.  I *love* the shovel version.

Comment: The 'offensive' card is played too often, in my opinion. Can't we use the word 'spade' at all? There was another issue with the use of the word 'gay' for 'stupid / unreliable' (eg 'this stool is gay') when there had been little respect paid to those who considered that the _original_ sense (carefree; merry) had been interfered with.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - So you're certain the origin is the digging implement?

Comment: Can we be certain of anything? But the evidence given in Etymon and dictionaries looks compelling.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Thanks for reminding me.  Your posts are astoundingly well researched and documented, so I can understand your wanting to spiff up mine.  But as it has my name on it, and I don't have any assurance you've attributed the original sources correctly, I'm not comfortable leaving your polishing as part of my post.  Also, I don't think that type of documentation is needed here. / Did I wait too long?  I don't see the "rollback" link.  Can you revert my post back to how it was?

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I have put a screenshot at the bottom of the question temporarily.  I've rolled things back in the past -- not sure why I can't find it today.

Comment: Visit the revisions (edit history). 4th revision by Tushar  Raj has the rollback link.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

These could work:

> [Telling it like it is](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/telling+it+like+it+is)
>
> *Informal*. to be blunt and forthright. <sub>[TFD]</sub>
>
> [Calling it like one sees it](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/call+it+like+one+sees+it)
>
> To be honest and unbiased; be deaf to influence <sub>[Dictionary.com]</sub>

Answer (score 11):

I would probably use "[not mincing words](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/not+mince+words)".

(Dictionary.com)

Answer (score 7):

My choice would be "X knows a hawk from a handsaw (when the wind is southerly)."

The distinction isn't quite as obvious as Hamlet's wording might suggest, since *handsaw* here refers to *hernshaw*, a heron. For a lengthier discussion of the hernshaw and of heron-hawking, see James Harting, [*The Ornithology of Shakespeare*](https://books.google.com/books?id=8_b1AwAAQBAJ&pg=PT99&dq=%22hernsaw%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=4tR0VYqACI61ogSMkoDQDw&ved=0CDAQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=%22hernsaw%22&f=false) (1871).

In any event, at the very least, I would have little confidence that a person who couldn't distinguish a hawk from a handsaw would correctly identify a spade as a spade.

---

On the other hand, according to Christine Ammer, *The American Heritage Dictionary of Idioms* (1997), "call a spade a spade" has a less sociologically fraught origin:

> **call a spade a spade** Speak frankly and bluntly, as in *You can always trust Mary to call a spade a spade.* This term comes from a Greek saying, *call a bowl a bowl*, that was mistranslated into Latin by Erasmus and came into English in the 1500s.

So, if you like, you can say "X calls a bowl a bowl"—and then explain to your puzzled hearers that you're just correcting Erasmus's little translation error from 500 years ago.

Comment: I really like "calling a bowl a bowl."  Even without the explanation, I think it works.

Answer (score 3):

If the shoe fits, wear it.

*shrugs*

Comment: Richard Pryor (I think) used to say 'If the shit fits'.

Answer (score 3):

You could *say it like it is*.  Alternatively, you could describe the situation *as is*.

Answer (score 1):

You can say:

> - ***To call a thing by its proper/right name***

> - To "call a spade a spade" is a figure of speech which explicitly *calls out something as it is, by its right name.* The implication is not to lie about what something is and instead to speak honestly and directly about a topic, specifically topics that others may avoid speaking about due to their sensitivity or the unpleasant or embarrassing nature of the subject.

Source: [Encyclo.Co.UK](https://www.encyclo.co.uk/meaning-of-Call_a_spade_a_spade), which in turn cited an outdated [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_a_spade_a_spade#Definition).

Answer (score 1):

To be honest (without regard for who gets hurt because you are being honest)

Answer (score 1):

In Spain we say 'To call bread to the bread and wine to the wine' or more colloquial 'to bread, bread and to wine, wine', meaning to avoid circumlocutions or the use of smooth euphemisms to say the truth with raw words. 
So, it is funny that a Spanish guy would reply to your question, about the context in which is used 'spade', saying: to bread, bread and to wine, wine.

Comment: How is that funny? (I don't get it)

Comment: Because you said you wanted to avoid this expression is some environments or context.

Comment: Sorry, Mitch. It wasn't you, but it is mentioned in the beginning of this topic.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase predates the use of the word "spade" as an ethnic slur against African-Americans, which was not recorded until 1928; however, in contemporary U.S. society, the idiom is often avoided due to potential confusion with the slur.

> Call'em as you see'em.
>
> Don't mince words.
>
> Cut the bull! Speak plainly.
>
> Call it what it is!

Answer (score 0):

A directly analogous non-metaphorical statement would be "*call it what it is*".

Answer (score 0):

I've always used,
"calling it like it is"

Answer (score 0):

- Let's "get down to the *[real] nitty-gritty*"

http://www.google.com/search?q=nitty+gritty+definition&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en

Answer (score 0):

You may formulate your feeling that way:

**"As Confucius said, the beginning of wisdom is to call things by their proper name**."

Answer (score 0):

I recently found myself with a need to express this idea while talking to a family member in another language.  Through that experience, I discovered this simple way of expressing the idea:

Instead of, Let's call a spade a spade, I said (the equivalent of) *Let's be clear*.  One could also say, *"Let's be clear about this."*

Answer (score 0):

How about the very American phrase "Let's cut to the chase'?

Comment: "Let's cut to the chase" means let's not waste time but rather go directly to the heart of the matter.  "Calling a spade a spade" means let's call a thing by its well-known name instead of using roundabout or euphemistic language.  I think these are different.

Answer (score -1):

If you wanted to be politically right - you could say " as a matter of fact" or "to put things in right perspective"