# opposite of 'break the news gently'?

Tags: phrases, popular-refrains

What is the opposite of breaking the news gently, without being mild or considerate, just giving it to them bluntly and being straightforward.

Comment: "Come right out with it."

Comment: Ambush him with the news.

Comment: "just giving it to them bluntly" - You already have your answer. If this is not good enough, then please explain why not, and what kind of alternative you need.

Comment: If it's a sudden announcement of bad news you have "dropped a bombshell".

Comment: Related: [“Calling a spade a spade”: synonymous expressions?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/250977)

Comment: Sometimes people are ["brutally honest"](https://www.google.it/search?q=plain+insensitive&oq=plain+insensitive&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#tbm=bks&q=%22brutally+honest%22), or just ["plain insensitive"](https://www.google.it/search?q=plain+insensitive&oq=plain+insensitive&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=%22plain+insensitive%22&tbm=bks), or "tactless".

Answer (score 1):

Consider ***[laying it on (someone)](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/lay-it-on-someone)***, an idiom which means:

> To tell; inform

It connotes bluntness and straightforwardness, at least more so than *break the news gently*.

The straightforwardness connotation can be seen in the definition from Urban Dictionary:

> ***[lay it on me](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Lay%20it%20on%20me)***
>
> tell me what you're saying, *be more clear*, or tell me something.

---

Another suggestion is ***hit (someone) with it***, an idiom which means something like:

> reveal or do something shocking to someone.

It has its root in the following sense of ***[hit](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/hit)***:

> *informal* Be affected by (an unfortunate and unexpected circumstance or event)

---

Here are example sentences involving both idioms:

> 1. His grandmother had died. At the breakfast table she laid it on him.
> 2. She hit him with the news of his father's death.

Answer (score 1):

In the first verse of [*I Don’t Want To Hear Anymore*](http://genius.com/The-eagles-i-dont-want-to-hear-anymore-lyrics), The Eagles seem to oppose the notion of “Telling it like it is” with that of “breaking it gently”:

> I know you're trying hard
>    To **break it gently to me**, now
>   But
>   there's no easy way
>   To **tell it like it is**, so baby ...

(lyrics, with emphasis added, retrieved from *Genius.com*)

> [**Tell it like it
>   is**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/tell+it+like+it+is)
>
> > Inf. Speak frankly.; Tell the truth no matter who is criticized or how
> >     much it hurts.
> >           “Come on man, tell it like it is!"
> >       "Well, I've got to
> >     tell it like it is.”

(from *McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs* via *The Free Dictionary by Farlex*)

Answer (score 0):

**Give it to them straight** i.e. getting straight to the point, saying it clearly, succinctly, honestly and without unnecessary sugar coating.

There are also metaphors you could try such as **rip of the plaster** (or bandaid) - pulling off a plaster can be less painful if done in a single quick motion - "Just rip off the plaster, tell me straight, am I going to die?"

Answer (score 0):

**Not pull any punches**

> to speak in an honest way without trying to be kind: Her image is that
>   of an investigative reporter who doesn't pull any punches.

(Definition of “not pull any/your punches” from the Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary & Thesaurus © Cambridge University Press)